# How to distribute a content of File into several nodes?

Tags: hadoop

I need to distribute the content of a file (upto 5 GB) over a Network such that each distributed node(XML or Simple File) of a file won't have replicate data and get synced with each other.

On a bigger note there could be more than 1000 of Big Files which needs to be take place in Distribution process.

Can i use Hadoop HDFS for Storing Big Files and use cluster Nodes for Distributed data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well yes, that's exactly what HDFS is used for.  You can control the replication factor easily if you don't want any duplication, but a replication factor of 2+ is usually recommended to allow for some high availability.

Comment: Can i run MapReducer job on different Servers (Multiple Servers) and uses HDFS clusters only for reading the data?

Comment: what do you mean by different Servers and HDFS clusters?

Comment: @AmitPal yes u can. It sounds like you very very new to distributed computing, you really ought to read a book on Hadoop or at least a few tutorials.